# Как установить и хранить полномочия пользователя исходя из URL параметров

Tags: javascript, ajax, объекты, url

В моем web приложении есть секция на которой реализованы "Мои заказы" (забегая вперед, я не могу использовать регистрацию). Когда кто-то заходит на неё (включая сотрудников) - отображаются заказы для конкретного пользователя (опущу сейчас этот момент, но вернусь позже).

У заказа есть только три дополнительных действия: "Отменить", "Подтвердить", "Дополнить". Пользователи делятся на три категории: клиент, менеджер, исполнитель. Каждая из них имеет свое право на одно или несколько действий.

Я не знаю наверняка, как явно хранить привилегии пользователей локально на момент сессии, коим образом, чтобы нельзя их было подделать через консоль или вкладку "source" в DevTools.

Рассмотрим пример, если ссылка имеет вид, как ex.ru/id=12345&user=m (код ниже писал "на лету")

```js
let user = { // станет, если данные будут найдены в бд 
 "user":"admin" // главное, остальное в объекте не касается вопроса // admin, потому что ...&user=m
};
let frm = new FormData();
let maxAjaxTimeout = 30000;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = new URL(window.location.href);

frm.append('user_id', url.searchParams.get('id'));
frm.append('user_sm', url.searchParams.get('user'));

xhr.timeout = maxAjaxTimeout;
xhr.open('post','some_name.php', true);

xhr.onload = () => Object.freeze(user = JSON.parse(xhr.response));

xhr.onerror = () => ajax_error(xhr.timeout, statusInternet, {
  "":"",
  "":"",
  "":""
});

xhr.send(frm);
```

Я заморозил свой объект, так, что через консоль свойства не меняются. Здесь вытекает вопрос - "А можно ли обратно разморозить его через консоль или как либо не меняя исходники"?

Код, который выше, он грузится первым. Он явно больше, потому что есть некие другие нюансы и проверки, которые сейчас ни к чему. Получается, что я знаю кто зашел - новый пользователь (или старый, но со стертыми данными и/или по прямой ссылке, однако в случае со старым клиентом - он получает на телефон прямую ссылку на свой/и заказ/ы) или сотрудник.

Далее, некие параметры в зависимости от обстоятельств отправляются на сервер, где возвращается `JSON` строка (заказы), а потом цикл выводит всё на экран:

```js
let i, html = '';
for(i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  // всякая магия
  // потом код <a ...>...</a>
  if(user.user === 'admin'){
    // html += все три действия
  }else if(user.user === 'perf'){
    // html += только два действия
  }else if(user.user === 'client'){
      // html += 1 действие
  }
}
```

Получается, что если объект нельзя разморозить ни как (я этого не могу знать точно, поэтому прошу советов), то подделать привилегии нельзя, ОДНАКО во вкладке Source в DevTools я могу изменить порядок проверки `if` и будучи `user.user === 'client'` получить код кнопок трех действий, если подделать код и запустить функцию.

Ок. Есть другой вариант событий, более странный для меня - все тоже самое, только в объект добавлять код трех действий для определенного пользователя. Так уже надежней.

Как же мне хранить привилегии, чтобы в зависимости от них, что-то делать и при этом пакостник не смог "поиграть" и например дополнить информацией заказ будучи не имея на это привилегий (сделать это может только менеджер)??

upd: Забыл сказать, что самое надежное, это отправить некие параметры на сервер и вернуть уже готовый код на страницу, но я плохо знаю `php` в частности сортировка массива, поэтому пытаюсь сделать всё на фронте...

Оффтоп:

Вопрос косвенно касается этого. Когда функция из `JSON` строки создает заказы (цикл `for`). На кнопку меню по заказу, которая открывает список возможных действий в зависимости от пользователя, добавляется уникальный идентификатор заказа (один на один заказ). Как его можно хранить по другому, чтобы легко получить и отправить на сервер, где по идентификатору найти заказ и сделать что-то с ним?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает хранить нужные вам параметры в переменных сессии? Записывать можете при первом входе на страницу, считывать на протяжении всего времени пока пользователь находится на сайте. 
Переменные сессии тоже конечно можно подделать, однако сделать это сложнее и требует определенных знаний.

Comment: В общем мой вопрос не совсем понятен, как я понял и в итоге решил сделать всё на сервере. Касательно моего вопроса - я отправляю на сервер параметры строки или хранилища (они будут `undefined`, если юзер впервые зашел), а на сервере искать. Получается, что вернется объект либо с привилегиями, если был найдет параметр в базе, либо новый вида `Object.freeze(user{"is":"client","id":"long_string"})`.  Так я точно определяю кто есть кто. Возвращать html код заявок я также решил с сервера. Посидел, поучил так сказать